# A better way to handle XML updation

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-xml

I have a DataGridView control where some values are popluted.
And also I have an xml file. The user can change the value in the Warning Column of DataGridView.And that needs to be saved in the xml file.

The below program just does the job

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

 //match the record
  foreach (var rule in xdoc.Descendants("Rule"))
  {
      foreach (var row in dgRulesMaster.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
      {
         if (rule.Attribute("id").Value == row.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
          {
              rule.Attribute("action").Value = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
          }
      }
  }

//save the record 
 xdoc.Save(filePath);
```

Matching the grid values with the XML document and for the matched values, updating the needed XML attribute.

Is there a better way to code this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the XML document a 1:1 relationship with DataGridView or is there other data in the XML document that isn't present in the DataGridView?

Comment: 1:1 relation is present

Comment: Then my question would be why would you need to update a single value or values in the document? You could simply do a scorched earth policy, delete the existing xml document and serialize out the DataGridView to XML and save it to the file system. Values should be the same no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var rules = dgRulesMaster.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                         .Select(x => new {
                                     RuleId = x.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                                     IsWarning = x.Cells[3].Value.ToString() });

var tuples = from n in xdoc.Descendants("Rule")
             from r in rules
             where n.Attribute("id").Value == r.RuleId
             select new { Node = n, Rule = r };

foreach(var tuple in tuples)
    tuple.Node.Attribute("action").Value = tuple.Rule.IsWarning;
```

This is basically the same, just a bit more LINQ-y. Whether or not this is "better" is debatable. One thing I removed is the conversion of `IsWarning` first to string, then to int and finally back to string. It now is converted to string once and left that way.

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection' could be found

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` to your cs file

Comment: dgRulesMaster is the DataGridView...It does not have "Select"

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar: `Select` is a LINQ extension method. Please also see update. I was missing a call to `Cast<DataGridViewRow>()`.

Answer (score -1):

XPath allows you to target nodes in the xml with alot of power. Microsoft's example of using the XPathNavigator to modify an XML file is as follows:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("contosoBooks.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("bk", "http://www.contoso.com/books");

foreach (XPathNavigator nav in navigator.Select("//bk:price", manager))
{
    if (nav.Value == "11.99")
    {
        nav.SetValue("12.99");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(navigator.OuterXml);
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx28tfx1(v=vs.80).aspx